# XPutImage() isnt displaying the image correctly

Tags: c, linux, x11, xlib

Welp im not a guy to quit...
But ive wasted around a full day and i have not reached even close

As with one comment pointed out i kinda forgot to say what was the objective/problem, well i want to open a X window, and display a simple png image with XPutImage.
***When i don't use a Pixmap it scatters seemingly random pixels everywhere regardless of how i format the incoming data. When i do use Pixmap the window remains black regardless of what i have tried...*** Everything's compiling with some minor unused variable warning's(which i solved since pushing to the repo)

```
image=readpng_verificar(args.decode_arg, &rowbytes, &pwidth, &pheight);
uint8_t *pont=MatrizParaVetor((uint8_t **)image.vetor, pheight, rowbytes);
pont=displaygrap_winrite(pont,pwidth, pheight, 8, rowbytes, args.decode_arg);
```

image is where i store 3 things namely 2 pointers related to pnglib(no probs) there and the last pointer which is a unsigned char **
for this we will only need to focus on the double pointed uint8 variable
so i pass that variable throught image.vetor so its transformed from a unsigned char ** into a simple unsigned char * (concatenating the different heights into a single vector instead of a matrix)
heres the code inside MatrizParaVetor()

```
uint8_t * MatrizParaVetor(uint8_t** matriz, uint32_t hei, size_t rwb){
    uint8_t *vetor=NULL;
    vetor =calloc(hei*rwb,sizeof(uint8_t));
    FILE * ok; 
    ok = fopen("teste.txt", "w");
    for (uint32_t y = 0; y < hei; y++){
        //memcpy(vetor[y], matriz[y], 30);
        //vetor=memmove(&(vetor[y*rwb]), matriz[y], 10);
        for (size_t x = 0; x < rwb; x+=4){
            vetor[y*x]=matriz[y][x];
            vetor[y*x+1]=matriz[y][x+1];
            vetor[y*x+2]=matriz[y][x+2];
            vetor[y*x+3]=0;
            //fprintf(ok, "%d\t%d\t%d\n",vetor[y*x],vetor[y*x+1],vetor[y*x+2]);
        }
        
    }
    fclose(ok);
    return vetor;
}
```

Some lines are just there for debugging(including the file IO) and yes im doing this in the steady and slow way(since others have failed).I just want it working for now.
I tried memcpy functions but it seemed to abort regardless of the size to copy or to move(even if it was extremely short values).

Ok now were putting that vector inside the last function where i spent hours trying to make it work

```
uint8_t *displaygrap_winrite(uint8_t *vetor, uint32_t wid, uint32_t hei, uint8_t bitdepth,size_t rwb, const char *title){
    XImage *img;
    gfx_open(&wid, &hei, (const char *)title); 
    img=gfxvetor_image(vetor, bitdepth, wid, hei, rwb);
    gfx_image(img, wid, hei);
    //gfx_flush();
    if(waitForKey((uint8_t)XK_Escape,&wid, &hei)==1){
        
    }
    gfx_close();
    return vetor;
}
```

And this will go to my heavily modified gfx library, which is was just a very basic graphics library that used X11 to display things on screen.

```
void gfx_image(XImage *image, uint32_t wid, uint32_t hei){

//  GC gc;
    //XGCValues values;
    //gc = XCreateGC(gfx_display, gfx_window, 0, &values);
    Pixmap bitmap;
    
    bitmap = XCreatePixmap(gfx_display,gfx_window, wid, hei, image->depth);
    //TODO FIX OFFSET FIX DEST MAYBE DO MULTITHREADED ACTIOn
    
    XInitImage(image);
    //int a= XDrawRectangle(gfx_display, gfx_window,gfx_gc,10,10,wid+10,hei+10);
    //image->byte_order = MSBFirst;
    //image->bitmap_bit_order = MSBFirst;
    XPutImage(gfx_display,bitmap,gfx_gc,image, 0,0,0,0,wid,hei);
    //XCopyArea(gfx_display, image, bitmap, gfx_gc, 0,0,wid, hei, 0, 0);
    XSetWindowBackgroundPixmap(gfx_display, gfx_window,bitmap);
    //int           /* bitmap_pad */,
    //XImage
}
XImage *gfxvetor_image(uint8_t *data, uint8_t bitdepth, uint32_t wid, uint32_t hei, size_t rwb){
    XImage *image;
    
    Visual *visual = DefaultVisual(gfx_display,0);
    int screen = DefaultScreen(gfx_display);
    int dplanes = DisplayPlanes(gfx_display, screen);
    //image=(XImage *)malloc(sizeof(XImage));
    //image = XGetImage(gfx_display,gfx_display,0,0,wid,hei,dplanes, ZPixmap);
    //printf("\n%d\n",dplanes);
    //image->f.create_image(gfx_display, visual, dplanes, ZPixmap, 0, (char *)data, wid, hei, (int)bitdepth, (int)rwb);
    image = XCreateImage(gfx_display, visual, dplanes, ZPixmap, 0, (char *)data, wid, hei, (int)bitdepth, (int)rwb);
    //image->byte_order=MSBFirst;

    //image->bytes_per_line=rwb;
    //image->bits_per_pixel=32;
    //XInitImage(image);

    return image;
}
```

I have already done the objective which was decoding a png image and using Xlib to display it on screen. Althought the method i used to display it, putting a dot and coloring it was ultra slow and this was one thing i wanted to do of my 100000 todo things the repo of the project is at https://github.com/Imeguras/xertin for the full extent of the code

I just want the picture to appear on screen and the Xlib manual isnt helping my fatigue
I am sorry, i sound a bit erratic, i am very tired but thanks for any feedback or help

Comment: `but it seemed to regardless of the size abort Ok now were` Please _use_ [punctuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation). Sentences end with a [full stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop). New sentences start with a capital letter. I do not understand your descriptions at all - it's just one blob. Please rewrite it in English. Why are you writing here? What _exactly_ is the issue you are having problem with? Please take a [tour], please read [ask] and I recommend checking [questions checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: @KamilCuk thank you for your fast reply, i have made it easier to read the thread, if theres anything i can do to help you guys understand the problem, like taking pictures or posting more code please tag me since  i rarely ask things here but it seems im running out of threads about this topic and every single one of them went into different paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your code and I think the following are the problems you are experiencing.

It looks like you are trying to fix byte order issues in the function `MatrizParaVetor`. It would be better to have the PNG library do that for you, so I suggest simplifying this function to the following:

```c
uint8_t * MatrizParaVetor(uint8_t** matriz, uint32_t hei, size_t rwb){
    uint8_t *vetor = calloc(hei*rwb,sizeof(uint8_t));
    uint8_t *pCurrent = vetor;
    for (uint32_t row = 0; row < hei; row++)
    {
        uint8_t *pRow = matriz[row];
        memcpy(pCurrent, pRow, rwb);
        pCurrent += rwb;
    }
    return vetor;
}
```

This just converts the array of pointers to rows to a contiguous pixel map.

If the image is in the correct format, the function `gfxvector_image` can be simplified to:

```c
XImage *gfxvetor_image(uint8_t *data, uint8_t bitdepth, uint32_t wid, uint32_t hei, size_t rwb){
    XImage *image;
    Visual *visual = DefaultVisual(gfx_display,0);
    int screen = DefaultScreen(gfx_display);
    int dplanes = DisplayPlanes(gfx_display, screen);
    image = XCreateImage(gfx_display, visual, dplanes, ZPixmap, 0, (char *)data, wid, hei, (int)bitdepth, (int)rwb);
    return image;
}
```

Similarly `gfx_image` can be simplified to:

```c
void gfx_image(XImage *image, uint32_t wid, uint32_t hei){
    XPutImage(gfx_display,gfx_window,gfx_gc,image, 0,0,0,0,wid,hei);
}
```

If you now run your code and you see the red colored image in test.png, then all is good. If the image appears blue, then you need to modify you `readpng_verificar` function. Search for the call to `png_set_alpha_mode` and afterward add:

```c
png_set_bgr(png_ptr);
```

This switches the decoding from red-green-blue component order to blue-green-red component order.

Comment: i checked your answer, ill read your response properly soon

Comment: THANKS, i should've reviewed what was wrong with my approach maybe i just ended up copying repeated code or shouldve persisted with the memcpy approach instead of giving up
I forgot to add in this for (int row = 0; row < hei; row++) theres a warning because you are comparing int row with uint32_t hei but thats a minor thing althought its annoying to see it compile

Comment: @Imeguras glad it all worked out for you. Thanks for pointing out the warning. Not sure how I missed that. Will update the answer. Good luck with your project!